# How to check a field associated with another field and return a value if there is a match

Tags: sql

Is there a way in SQL to check if a field is associated with another field and in the select statement return some value. Here is what I mean:

If I have a table like

```
Id       Language
-----------------
1        Spanish
2        English
1        English
3        English
4        English
2        Spanish
2        English
```

How can I return something like

```
Id           SpanishAssociated
------------------------------
1            Yes
2            Yes
3            No
4            No
```

The problem I'm running into now is if I do something like

```
SELECT Id, SpanishAssocated = (CASE SpanishAssociated WHEN 'Spanish' THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'NO' END)
FROM MyTable
```

I get a table that looks like

```
Id           SpanishAssociated
------------------------------
1            Yes
1            No
2            Yes
2            No
2            No
3            No
4            No
```

The actual query is much more complex, but this is general idea. Basically I just want a column that has a yes if "Spanish" is associated with a users Id (not unique in the table) (i.e. there is at least one row in the table I am selecting from where "Spanish" appears with a user's id.

Answer (score 0):

Try if that works for you:

```
SELECT Id, SpanishAssocated = MAX(CASE SpanishAssociated WHEN 'Spanish' THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'NO' END)
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY Id;
```

Note - it relies on string comparison ('Yes' is greater than 'NO') and may not work for some collations

Comment: It still returns duplicate rows. I think this may be the general direction I want to go in though. There has to be a way to solve this using an aggregate function.

Comment: This version of the query can return only one "SpanishAssocated" flag per distinct Id. Since you mentioned the real query is more complex, I guess there are some joins that add records to resultset. But I believe one or other aggregate function will give you desired output...

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested I use a subquery and join it back into my main query which worked well.

I ended up with something like this

```
SELECT OtherTables.Id, Language = (CASE WHEN X.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END)
--Select a bunch of other stuff from the other tables here
FROM OtherTables
--A bunch of other table joins go here
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Id FROM MyTable WHERE Language = 'Spanish') X
ON X.Id = MyTable.Id
GROUP BY OtherTables.Id, X.Id -- and other stuff I selected
```